# Does Prabowo really have any reasonable reason to believe he is winning?

Tags: indonesia

Quick counts clearly says that Jokowi wins by BIG margin. By 9%

Yet Prabowo insists that he get 60% of the vote.

Is he blatantly lying?

https://www.theaustralian.com.au/nation/world/loser-prabowo-claims-victory-on-indonesia/news-story/aaf26f3b01632117d7f7b3f2f84ed0c5

Comment: Link has a paywall, sadly. Can you post a quote or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he lost the previous (2014) election Prabowo ["withdrew"](https://www.smh.com.au/world/prabowo-subianto-withdraws-from-indonesian-presidential-election-on-day-vote-was-to-be-declared-20140722-zvte5.html) from it as the results were becoming clear, invoking "massive cheating that is structured and systematic"

> Former army strongman Prabowo Subianto claims to have ‘‘withdrawn’’ from the presidential race on the day it was to be announced that he had lost.
>
> In an extraordinary statement in his campaign headquarters on Tuesday afternoon, Mr Prabowo said he entirely rejected the judgment delivered by 133 million Indonesians at the ballot box on July 9, because it was the result of ‘‘massive cheating that is structured and systematic’’.
>
> He said the country’s Electoral Commission had failed in its duty to democracy, so he withdrew his participation from the process. He also suggested, though not explicitly, that he would not take his appeal to Indonesia’s constitutional court.
>
> Later, his legal representative, Mahendradatta, confirmed to kompas.com that, “only those with legal standing can go to the Constitutional Court - that is those who are registered as presidential candidates ... By withdrawing we … no longer have legal standing”. [...]
>
> Late on Monday, police were lining the city streets around the Electoral Commission after threats from Mr Prabowo’s camp that he would send thousands of supporters to ‘‘guard’’ and ‘‘secure’’ the vote.

The initial part of that sounds very similar with what he said in [April this year](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/apr/13/dont-teach-me-democracy-an-uneasy-audience-with-indonesias-prabowo):

> Less than a week before the presidential election, most credible polls show Jokowi with a double-digit lead, but the Prabowo camp claims their internal polling shows the former general is in front, although they have declined to release the details.
>
> “I feel very strong,” says Prabowo, “If the powers that be want to cheat massively they will be going against the will of the people.”

Then and now, at least to some extent, it seems a strategy devised to avoid conceding defeat and keeping his supporters energized with claims of fraud, even after the election.

Although just paraphrasing, Reuters [reported](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-indonesia-election-prabowosubianto-pr/indonesian-former-general-fires-up-masses-in-second-run-at-presidency-idUSKCN1RQ03O) about this election:

> Just days ahead of the vote, Prabowo and his campaign team have cast doubt on the credibility of voter lists and the integrity of election machinery, vowing to contest the results and even mobilize street protests if they discern any cheating.
>
> The campaign has also said internal and external poll numbers give Prabowo a clear lead, but has declined to explain its methodology.

The theme that election is going to be stolen (by some elites, against the people) meshes well with his other populist messages, although the latter seems newer...

> “The Indonesian motherland is being raped,” Prabowo told another massive rally in a stadium in central Jakarta, as tens of thousands of supporters, many dressed in white Islamic clothes, chanted his name.

"Rigged system" and "we're being taken advantage of" sound pretty familiar populist themes by now. (And yes, Reuters does draw a parallel with Trump.)

Comment: This answer could be improved by being more concrete regarding what "fraud or something like that" means. A direct quote from Prabowo where he explains his reasons would be great. Otherwise this answer sounds as if we are trying to painting Prabowo in a bad light by making his arguments seem incoherent. Maybe his arguments *are* incoherent, but if that is the case, the burden of proof lies with us.

Comment: As far as I know, he has absolutely no reasonable reason to believe he's winning. So this answer is good enough. I just want to make sure. That guy makes many stupid claim.